# Error with openid4java

Tags: java, openid, openid4java

I found this project 
https://code.google.com/p/idp4java which depends on openId4Java

but I am facing the following problem when I am running it

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.openid4java.message.IndirectError cannot be cast to org.openid4java.message.AuthSuccess

type Exception report

message org.openid4java.message.IndirectError cannot be cast to org.openid4java.message.AuthSuccess

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openid4java.message.IndirectError cannot be cast to org.openid4java.message.AuthSuccess
    net.vinant.idp4java.openid4javaImpl.OpenId4JavaProtocolImplementation.checkId(OpenId4JavaProtocolImplementation.java:245)
    net.vinant.idp4java.openid4javaImpl.OpenId4JavaProtocolImplementation.handle(OpenId4JavaProtocolImplementation.java:105)
    net.vinant.idp4java.EndpointServlet.doPost(EndpointServlet.java:43)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 logs.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing

```
// messageResponse = manager.authResponse(parameterList, userSelectedId, userSelectedClaimedId, true);
         messageResponse = manager.authResponse(parameterList, opLocalId, opLocalId, true);
```

to this code

```
messageResponse = manager.authResponse(parameterList, userSelectedId, userSelectedClaimedId, true);
        // messageResponse = manager.authResponse(parameterList, opLocalId, opLocalId, true);
```